# Is there documentation on how to upgrade a Joomla extension from 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: joomla, migrate

I'm in the process of migrating my Joomla 1.5 web site to Joomla 2.5.  I'm using all of the migration tools available, but I have a few, key, extensions, most of which are pretty simple, that are not being upgraded to 2.5.  Is there any clear documentation on what must be done to make these extensions compatible with Joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - on [docs.joomla.org](http://docs.joomla.org/) you will find "[Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6)".

Joomla! 1.6 was the platform change point so even though it's called 1.6 the main architectural changes were in place for what became 2.5